# after Backbone.history.navigate can't go previous page

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I'm using backbone like below try to make if user click `.next` do change url and ajax send fragment load data.
I have problem after user click `.next` only the url be changed, the browser go previous page can't work,  how to solve it?

also I'm just start learning backbone, please help me review my code any suggestion will be appreciate.

```
var Core = function() {

    var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
        routes: {
            '': 'func0', // root/article
            'page/:id': 'func1' // root/article/page/:id
        },
        func0: function(p0) {  // ajax send fragment load data
        },
        func1: function(p1) {  // ajax send fragment load data
        }
    });

    var Next = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: '.next',
        events: {
            'click': 'onClick'
        },
        onClick: function() {
            // console.log(Backbone.history.fragment); 
            // fragment to Backbone.history.navigate('page/'+fragment, {trigger: true, replace: true});

            // for example
            Backbone.history.navigate('page/10', {trigger: true, replace: true});
        }
    });
    return {
        init: function() {
            var router = new Router();
            Backbone.history.start({pushState: true, hashChange: false, root: '/root/public/article/'});

            var next = new Next();
        }
    }
}();
```

html

```
<div class="next">next</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your browser can't go backwards because you call `Backbone.history.navigate` with `replace: true` option, which updates the URL without creating an entry in the browser's history. So the correct code would be:

```
Backbone.history.navigate('page/10', {trigger: true, replace: false});
```

Source: http://backbonejs.org/#Router-navigate